# How to uninstall a Steam update?

Tags: steam

I  used different site to understand their command and such tried to delete it. I delete file use us... But still, all this comes out steam installer for update-notifier (doesn't let me add picture I don't know why).

If I try  `rm -rf ~/. local/share/Steam && rm -rf ~/. steam` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> it says: `Command doesn't exist`.

I followed the  instruction and everything and I don't know what else to try

--

Thanks kya for answer. I have unbuntu. Still steam doesn't work on it. I downloaded a game and it says `Uknown source. Can't start it`.

I said **ignore**. But next time I wanted to play it said it couldn't start it because of unknown source.

I deleted all, started ubuntu store, downloaded steam installer and clicked on start. Nothing happens so then I moved all on bin and delete.

I don't think I will try again in a few month. I will be able to buy a Microsoft license or a new pc so I will just live with it. 
Also the link was 4 ways to uninstall steam. It shows apple, microsoft and linux, but the 4th I don't know.

Comment: To start with, 1) what is the URL of that different site you used, as you mentioned in the first line of your question? 2) Which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: It would also help to know what game you were trying to play since that ultimately is what you are really having issues with.  There is also a Linux category on the Steam forums that might be more specialized in solving your issues, it can't hurt to ask there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Installing steam on Ubuntu 19.10 using terminal:

- Download a package: `wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb`
- Install it: `cd ~/Downloads && sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb && sudo apt install -f`
  It asks about Starting steam to configure it for current user. I click the button and input my user's password when it prompts.
  In my case it also wants to install some additional packages:

  ```
   Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
      libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
  ```

  Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start packages downloading and installing.
  At the end it asks to `Press return to continue:`. I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it closes terminal window. After this Steam window with **Updating Steam...** progress bar appears a few times.

At the end, the window appears:

[image: steam window]

To uninstall it, run in terminal:

```
sudo apt purge steam-launcher
sudo rm -fr ~/.local/share/Steam && rm -fr ~/.steam
```

I have Gnome Wayland DE, with proprietary Nvidia GT220 drivers properly installed from repositories and `4.19.100-xanmod48` kernel.